# How to pass non string related data into a get request web api

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api

I am calling an asp.net mvc web api controller action from an angular 2 application. I can accept objects from the call like this:

```
    [Route("api/getItems")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ReturnObject GetItems(DateRangeVM dateRange){
    }
```

However, I do not want to do a post, I want it to be a get, so when I am calling this from angular 2, I want something like this:

```
return this.http.post(this.API_URL_BASE + '/api/getItems', dateRange, defaultOptions).map((response: Response) => {
      return <any[]>response.json();
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

but actually more like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.API_URL_BASE + '/api/getItems', dateRange, defaultOptions).map((response: Response) => {
      return <any[]>response.json();
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

However, this last option does not accept data as the second option. I do not want to pass the data as string arguments because this is too messy when the data becomes more complex.

Comment: `$http.get` can take only query parameters, are you meaning to do this - `this.API_URL_BASE + '/api/getItems?dateRange=' + dateRange` ?

Comment: But you shouldn't, sending payload in query can be altered and is not a good practice. Why not stick with `$http.post`?

Comment: "I do not want to pass the data as string arguments because this is too messy when the data becomes more complex." The parameter is not string, but a set of objects within another object.

Comment: @Sajal post i thought should only be done if you are adding or removing data or alike. Seeing as this is a query, it feels wrong to be doing a post. Is it not wrong?

Comment: Pure REST based approach would be to break the parameters in the object and query them in a string for an `http.get`. There is no harm in using post for all/any operation since its a better protocol for providing better data security.

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929376/bind-query-parameters-to-a-model-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Perfect @DawoodAwan that is exactly what I was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FromUri attribute to bind the query string to a complex object. Angular will need to send each property of the class as a query string parameter.

```
public ReturnObject GetItems([FromUri] DateRangeVM dateRange){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but here is how I approach a similar problem...

Here is a sample Users controller.  This method is intended to return all users, or any users that match a specified start date.

```
public IEnumerable<User> Get(DateTime? startDate = null)
{
    return _userRepo.Get(startDate);
}
```

In an angular service I defined the following:

```
function getUsers(startDate) {
    var users = $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: config.remoteServiceName +'users/',
        params: {
            startDate: startDate
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        var values = [];
        angular.forEach(response.data, function (value) {             
            values.push(User.apiResponseTransformer(value));
        });
        return values;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
        throw errorResponse;
    });

    return users;
}
```

Here is a link to another SO question that has been answered which provides some information on why using the request body on a GET is not desirable:

[Read content body from a HTTP GET in C# WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590957/read-content-body-from-a-http-get-in-c-sharp-webapi)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Zoop, I am using angular 2 (version 4). Maybe someone else will find it useful though. Thanks anyway.